# Using conda build to build win32 and win64 packages in 1 go

Tags: python, windows, conda, conda-build

My pure python scripts are 32 bits or 64 bits agnostic but my dependencies are not. I want to use cython to speed up some functions making the package not pure python. And I want to use them on windows with python 32 bits or 64 bits.

Is there a way to build with 1 conda recipe a conda python package for `win32` and `win64` platforms?

One would assume that runtime dependencies (e.g. Numpy, etc.) are available for both platforms. Setup could either start from a miniconda 32 or 64 bits installation.

I have read the documentation differentiating the `build`, `host` requirements in meta.yaml, the conda build variants, and the architecture virtual packages but I am struggling to see if a clever combination of these functionalities would allow me to build both packages in one go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few experimentations, I found the solution to my question. If you put the following in `conda_build_config.yaml`:

```
target_platform:
  - win-32
  - win-64
```

And make sure you're using the Jinja compiler functions in the `requirements/build:` section of the recipe `meta.yaml`:

```
build:
  - {{ compiler('c')  }}
  - {{ compiler('cxx')  }}
```

then `conda build` will build both `win-32` and `win-64` packages in one go. (I used `conda-build` **64 bits** but i do not think it matters).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This doesn't work

---

> Is there a way to build with 1 conda recipe a conda python package for win32 and win64 platforms?

`conda convert --platform all` for the lazy execution, or build it on 64-bit and `conda convert --platform win-32` to get just the two builds you ask for.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-convert.html

This is technically two steps (build and convert) but it could be wrapped into another script to do in one go.

Comment: conda convert would only work with pure python packages which would not be the case when I start using cython, this is how I understand the docs?

Comment: You're right, apologies for the incorrect answer